# файл базы данных SQLite не создается

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Файл базы данных SQLite не создается. Что бы было проще, папке **Download** телефона должна создаться пустая база данных **abc.db** После создания, для проверки, должен быть выведен путь. Ничего не происходит, папка пуста, путь не выводится. Что не так? Далее, полный код и скриншоты. 
***main.dart***

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str = 'Hello World!';

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 _funInitDb() async {
  Directory? folder = await getDownloadsDirectory();
  String path = folder!.path.toString() + '/' + 'abc.db';
  var db = await openDatabase(path);
  //для проверки выводим путь
  _str = '${db.path}';
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
       onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
         _funInitDb();
        });
       },
       splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
       ),
       child: Text(
        'OK',
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.deepPurple,
         fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 36.0,
       color: Colors.green
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

папка в телефоне пуста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
скриншот приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не дали разрешения на запись к папке Download.

Добавьте это в [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#perms) (путь к файлу: `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Дальше через плагин [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), вы должны узнать статус разрешения. Если оно не выдано, запросить разрешение:

```
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}
```

После можно вызывать `_funInitDb()`

Comment: Здравствуйте уважаемый MiT! Огромное Вам спасибо. getDownloadsDirectory() только для настольных операционных систем. Разрешения я  добавлял. Они нужны для getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: [Судя по документации да](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getDownloadsDirectory.html). можете попробовать: https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage